# Postgres function to return an int array

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I am dipping my toe into the world of Postgres stored procedures/functions and have run into some teething difficulties.  Following the documentation and various examples I have come across I wrote the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_intersect(a INT[],b INT[]) RETURNS INT[] AS $$
BEGIN
 DECLARE result INT[];
 SELECT INTO result ARRAY(
 SELECT UNNEST($1) INTERSECT  SELECT UNNEST($2)
 return result;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

only to see errors such as

> Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"
>   LINE 4: SELECT INTO result ARRAY(
>   CONTEXT: invalid type name "INTO result ARRAY( 
>   SELECT UNNEST($1) INTERSECT SELECT UNNEST($2) 
>   return result"

I clearly am doing something wrong here but I fail to see what it might be.  As far as I can tell, I have

- correctly declared the two parameters, and their types, in the function
- Indicated that the function should return an int array as its result
- Declared a variable to hold the result
- Populated it with a select
- returned the result

I find the Postgres function syntax rather arcane but perhaps that is just down to my newbie perceptions. How can I get this syntax right?

Answer (score 0):

You have unbalanced parentheses, for one.

I assume you are looking for

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_intersect(int[], int[]) RETURNS int[]
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
'SELECT array_agg(a) FROM ((SELECT unnest($1) AS x) INTERSECT 
 (SELECT unnest($2) AS y)) AS a(a)';
```

Comment: I eventually used `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_intersect(BIGINT[],BIGINT[]) RETURNS BIGINT[] LANGUAGE sql
AS 'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT UNNEST($1) INTERSECT SELECT UNNEST($2));';`

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your PL/pgSQL structure:

The `DECLARE`  block [needs to be before](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) the first BEGIN.

The `INTO` part when storing the result of a query into a variable [goes after](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) the SELECT list.

Not an error, but there is no need to reference the parameters by position:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_intersect(a INT[],b INT[]) RETURNS INT[] 
AS $$
DECLARE 
  result INT[];

BEGIN
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT UNNEST(a) INTERSECT  SELECT UNNEST(b))
    into result;

  return result;

END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But short functions like that are much better written with `language sql` (as shown in Laurenz's answer), not PL/pgSQL needed.